# How to show "load more stories" in my jsp web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp

Firstly, Let me clear your doubt that what I'm looking for. I googled already and tons of result but My question is:

***I want to show `Load more stories` into my web application and it's fetching stories from MySql database, something like:***

```
<div align="center"><font color="#CC0099" size="4">&#9733;·.·´¯`·.·&#9733; HAPPY NEW YEAR &#9733;·.·´¯`·.·&#9733;<br></font></div>
<%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news", "foo", "foo");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from main_news order by news_id desc");
            while(rs.next()){
                String my_news=rs.getString("my_news");
    %>
<div class="wpb_wrapper" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcbc;">
<section>
<!-- Here, would be my news.... -->
    <%=my_news %>
</section>
</div><br><br><br>
<%
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
<p style="text-align:center;">No more stories here..</p> 
</div>
```

Can you please just help me, I've tons of stories and now i want to change it something like `Load more Stories.

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: read up on how to use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what you need.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll --> can be integrated using jQuery

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ --> scrolldown to the bottom to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax, click [w3school](http://www.w3school.com.cn/ajax/index.asp).

JavaScript In your page:

```
var xmlHttp
function loadmore()
 {
    //here you can send a request to a jsp(such as getmorestory.jsp) or a servlet to get data of stories.
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
      alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
      return
    } 
    var url="getmorestory.jsp"
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null)
} 
function stateChanged() 
{ 
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
  { 
     document.getElementById("news").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText 
  } 
}
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
     {
         // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
         xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
    catch (e)
     {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
         xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
         xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
  }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

---

you can change your html code like this:

```
<section id="news">
     <!-- Here, would be my news.... -->
     <%=my_news %>
</section>

<p style="text-align:center;" onclick="loadmore()">No more stories here..</p>
```

---

In getmorestory.jsp, you can code like this:

```
<%
    try{
        if(session.getAttribute("RequestNum")!=null){
           session.SetAttribute("RequestNum") = 0;
    }
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news", "foo", "foo");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
//add a param like RequestNum to session to control
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from main_news order by news_id desc limit  session.getParameter("RequestNum"), session.getParameter("RequestNum")+10 ");
     session.SetAttribute("RequestNum") = session.getAttribute("RequestNum")+10;
        while(rs.next()){
            String my_news=rs.getString("my_news");
    //here output my_news, it will be send back to xmlHttp.responseText 
    out.print(my_news);
%>
```

---

The code may has many errors, but you can do like this way...

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know `Chinese`. Can you please update it? if you don't mind..