# Onclick of link load more feeds

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script that enables users on my website to read more feeds on click of a link (Lord More Feeds) with ajax. meaning there are more to read but its hidden and onclick more feeds are shown and it work perfectly. Now i'm developing a jquery mobile site version of my website but it seems that script is not able to work as it does on the website. when i click Lord More feeds it fails to load

```
$(function() {
    //More Button
    $('.more').live("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id) {
            $("#more" + id).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "source_more.asp",
                data: "lastmsg=" + id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("ol#updates").append(html);
                    $("#more" + id).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');

        }

        return false;

    });
});
```

please help

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: `.live` was removed in jQuery 1.9. You should be using `.on`.

Comment: i use version v1.8.3

Answer (score 1):

if you are using newer versions of jquery. the .live() method is deprecated.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

from http://api.jquery.com/live/

here is the usage of the .on() function applied on your code:

> $(function() {
>
> ```
>   //More Button
>   $(document).on("click",".more", function() {
>     var id = $(this).attr("id");
>     if (id) {
>         $("#more" + id).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
>
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "source_more.asp",
>             data: "lastmsg=" + id,
>             cache: false,
>             success: function(html) {
>                 $("ol#updates").append(html);
>                 $("#more" + id).remove();
>             }
>         });
>     } else {
>         $(".morebox").html('The End');
>
>     }
>
>     return false;
>
> }); });
> ```

Comment: please can you phrase it in my code since i'm new to jquery

Comment: when i click still nothing happens. am using version 1.8.3 of jquery

Comment: any chance to post your html to question?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll --> can be integrated using jQuery

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ --> scrolldown to the bottom to see the effect.

I have the same answer here..

[How to show "load more stories" in my jsp web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664474/how-to-show-load-more-stories-in-my-jsp-web-application/27664568#27664568)